# Multiple dropdown nav bootstrap

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am trying to make a multiple dropdown in bootstrap, but the 3rd level is not showing. The point of this nav is when u click on the first level the 2nd level pops out and on this level there should be 3 items. These items should have a dropdown aswel but they are not showing. (The nav is xs mode)

Here is my navbar code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs" id="top-menueen">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw fa-2x"></i> <span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-fw fa-2x"></i> <span>News</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-fw fa-2x"></i>Statistics <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">A<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">A.A</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw fa-2x"></i>People <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

I think this should help you alot.

EDIT: Sorry i just saw you are using "visible-xs", so i guess this is made for mobile devices.

If your using this for mobile devices try to set it up with javascript / jquery like here: http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz

Comment: I can't see my problem. When i click on my statistics the dropdown opens and shows (A, B, C), but when i want to go deeper on the A, the menu closes and shows the first 4 elements (Home, news, statistics, people).

Comment: You can solve this with css (open submenu on hover) like in the link i gave you in my answer, or use javascript / jquery like here: http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz to open submenu on click.